# Objective-C - Firebase retrieving data from database and populate in table

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p9Ks.png)

I have a Firebase database setup (please refer to the picture).

I have a "FeedViewController" to display the contents of each post in the database. A user may post one or more posts.

When retrieving these posts from the Firebase snapshot and storing them onto a dictionary, I find that this dictionary's values are not accessible outside of the Firebase's observeEventType function.

My idea was to retrieve these key-value pairs, store them onto a NSObject custom class object (Post *post) and use this object to load the table view for my "FeedViewController". Inside the observeEventType function, I am able to access the object's values, but outside, I'm not. As a result, I don't know how to use these values to populate the table view in my FeedViewController. I understand that this observeEventType function is an asynchronous callback, but I don't know how to access the values of the object and populate my table. I don't have a clue what the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() function is doing here. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

FeedViewController.m

```
#import "FeedViewController.h"
#import "Post.h"
#import "BackgroundLayer.h"
#import "SimpleTableCell.h"
#import "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h"
#import "FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h"
#import "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKGraphRequest.h"
@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseAuth;
@import FirebaseStorage;
@import FirebaseDatabase;

@interface FeedViewController()

@property (strong, nonatomic) Post *post;

@end

@implementation FeedViewController

-(void) viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

_ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

self.post = [[Post alloc] init];

/*

_idArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


_postDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
_idDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
_postID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

_userName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_placeName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_addressLine1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_addressLine2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_ratings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_desc = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_userEmail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_userIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 */
[self fetchData];

 NSLog(@"Emails: %@", _post.userID);


}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer blueGradient];
bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];

FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;

if (user != nil)
{
    //fbFirstName.text = user.displayName;
    //fbEmail.text = user.email;
    NSURL *photoUrl = user.photoURL;
    NSString *userID = user.uid;
    //NSString *uploadPath = [userID stringByAppendingString:@"/profile_pic.jpg"];
    //NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoUrl];
    //ProfilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    FIRStorage *storage = [FIRStorage storage];
    FIRStorageReference *storageRef = [storage referenceForURL:@"gs://foodsteps-cee33.appspot.com"];

    NSString *access_token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"fb_token"];

    FBSDKGraphRequest *friendList = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=friends"
                                parameters:nil
                                  tokenString: access_token
                                  version:nil
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [friendList startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {

        if(error == nil)
        {
            //NSLog(@"%@", result);
            NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;
            NSDictionary *dict = [dictionary objectForKey:@"friends"];

            _idArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for(int i = 0; i < [[dict objectForKey:@"data"] count]; i++) {

                [_idArray addObject:[[[dict objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id"]];
            }

            //NSLog(@"%@", idArray);
        }

        else {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
    }];


}
}

-(void) fetchData {

_refHandle = [[_ref child:@"users"]     observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
                                           withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot)
              {
                  NSDictionary *postDict = snapshot.value;
                  NSLog(@"%@", postDict);

                  for( NSString *aKey in [postDict allKeys] )
                  {
                      // do something like a log:
                      _post.userID = aKey;
                  }

                  //_post.
                  //[_post setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:postDict];
                  [self.tableView reloadData];

            }];

NSLog(@"Emails: %@", _post.userID);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

[self.tableView reloadData];

});
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[_ref child:@"users"] removeObserverWithHandle:_refHandle];
}

@end
```

Post.m

```
#import "Post.h"

@implementation Post


- (instancetype)init {

return [self initWithUid:@""
               andPostid:@""
             andUsername:@""
                 andDesc:@""
              andRatings:@""
            andPlacename:@""
         andAddressLine1:@""
         andAddressLine2:@""
                andEmail:@""];
}

- (instancetype)initWithUid:(NSString *)userID
            andPostid:(NSString *)postID 
andUsername: (NSString *)userName
andDesc:(NSString *)desc
andRatings:(NSString *)ratings
andPlacename: (NSString *)placeName
andAddressLine1: (NSString *)addressLine1
andAddressLine2: (NSString *)addressLine2
andEmail: (NSString *)userEmail {

self = [super init];
if(self) {
    self.userID = userID;
    self.postID = postID;
    self.userName = userName;
    self.desc = desc;
    self.ratings = ratings;
    self.placeName = placeName;
    self.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    self.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    self.userEmail = userEmail;
}

return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is what I tried to do initially. But I had problems accessing it in cellforrowatindexpath. the thing that works for me is.

```
- (void)configureDatabase :(NSUInteger)postsAmount{

_ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
// Listen for new messages in the Firebase database
_refHandle = [[[[_ref child:@"posts"]queryOrderedByKey] queryLimitedToLast:postsAmount]observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

        [_posts insertObject:snapshot atIndex:0];
   }];
}
```

Then in viewdidappear

```
        [self configureDatabase:_numberOfPosts];
```

then lastly

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

FIRDataSnapshot *postsSnapshot = _posts[indexPath.section];

NSDictionary *post = postsSnapshot.value;
//use key values to create your views.
}
```

also include

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray<FIRDataSnapshot *> *posts;
```

What this does is queries firebase for your values and receives snapshots. those snapshots are then placed in your _posts array and then you can access them in other methods.